# Function is not defined python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I am trying to use the return from my scan_db() return to pass it through to the next function json_create(response) and use the return from my json_create(response) to pass to my broadcast_string(Sensor_IP, jsonString).

Every time I try to run the program I get the error "NameError: name 'response' is not defined" I cannot find useful examples anywhere.

I am using python 2.7

```
mycursor = conn.cursor()


def scan_db():
    print "Scanning DB"
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM outputs ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;")
    response = mycursor.fetchall()

    return response


def json_create(response):
    ID, Sensor_ID, Sensor_IP, State, Pending_Update, TimeStamp = response[0]

    print "Json string creating"
    print ""
    print "ID", ID
    print "Sensor Name", Sensor_ID
    print "Sensor IP", Sensor_IP
    print "State", State
    print "Pending update", Pending_Update
    print "Time", TimeStamp
    print ""

    jsonSwitch = {'Sensor_Name': Sensor_ID, 'Sensor_IP': Sensor_IP, 'State': State,
              'Pending_Update': Pending_Update}

    jsonString = json.dumps(jsonSwitch)

    return jsonString, Sensor_IP


def broadcast_string(Sensor_IP, jsonString):
    UDP_IP = Sensor_IP  # broadcast
    UDP_PORT = 5002

    print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
    print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
    print "message:", jsonString

    cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    cs.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    cs.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    cs.sendto(jsonString, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


while True:
   print "while loop started"
   scan_db()
   print "scanning db"
   json_create(response)
   print "creating Json string"
   broadcast_string(Sensor_IP, jsonString)
   print "broadcasting packet"
   time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stored the result which `scan_db()` returns so in `json_create(response)` the `response` is nothing. Try creating a variable `response` and setting its contents equal to the value `scan_db()` returns like so:

```
while True:
   print "while loop started"
   response = scan_db() # edit this line
   print "scanning db"
   json_create(response)
   print "creating Json string"
   broadcast_string(Sensor_IP, jsonString)
   print "broadcasting packet"
   time.sleep(2)
```

similarly you could also do `json_create(scan_db())`

Comment: But the parameters `Sensor_IP` and `jsonString` of `broadcast_string(Sensor_IP, jsonString)`  also not defined...

Comment: @Tangwz I'm not sure if those are globals, but I would expect them to be undefined as well otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this piece of code:

```
while True:
   print "while loop started"
   scan_db()
   print "scanning db"
   json_create(response)
   # the rest of your code
   # ...
```

by

```
while True:
   print "while loop started"
   # create a new response variable
   response = scan_db()
   print "scanning db"
   json_create(response)
   # the rest of your code
   # ....
```

**Explication:**

Your `scan_db()` method will return the `response` variable that you'll use in your `json_create(response)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop, You should

```
while True:
   print "while loop started"
   response = scan_db()
   print "scanning db"
   jsonString, Sensor_IP = json_create(response)
   print "creating Json string"
   broadcast_string(Sensor_IP, jsonString)
   print "broadcasting packet"
   time.sleep(2)
```

Maybe you should learn what is `local variable`?

Comment: i now get NameError: name 'Sensor_IP' is not defined

Comment: @moe.Patel I edit the answer, you should get the function `json_create`'s return, and pass the return variable to the next function.